# GLPaint Subview issue

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, ios7

I am new to iPhone application development and currently working on a simple paint application for iPad. I use GLPaint source code to start with.  I have 2 buttons on my main window
1)settings
2)save image

In settings,I had create xib with slider that change the colour of brush stroke. After selecting colour, the setting page is remove from superview.

My question is that,when setting view is removed,after that I draw line on painting view than previous drawing is erased when touches moved method called. I want to redraw on the same previous drawing with different colour chooses by slider into setting view.

This issue is only happen when i run my app on iPad devise,but in iPad simulator it works fine.

can any one has a better idea about this ?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint to "glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);" line in your project and see if it gets called and by what. If this is not the case the whole buffer might have been recreated so search also for "glGenFramebuffers" and set breakpoints.

Comment: this two method can't be called ,if i set breakpoint..
- (void) renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end
when this method get calls then my painting view getting nil.